# Simplifications of nth roots of complex numers.

Tags: complex-numbers

Is it easy to find that $( a + ib)^n$ is equal to a certain complex number, say $p+iq$, by just using Newton's binomial theorem. But how to find in general that $\sqrt[n]{p+iq} = a+ib$, where $a, b, p, q$ are real numbers that can be expressed by radicals? I known that this cannot be done in the general case (only square roots of complex numbers can be found exactly in all cases), but I am supposing that $p+iq$ is a perfect nth power. When the radical is reducible in this way, how this reduction can be done?

REMARK: Exponential form (or polar form)  and decimal approximations aren't allowed, because the problem is to express $\sqrt[n]{p+iq} = a+ib$, where $a, b$ are real radicals, and thus this specific problem excludes the use of transcendental functions as an answer.

Comment: Write $p+iq$ in exponential form $re^{i\theta}$, then apply the $n$-th root function to get $r^{\frac{1}{n}} e^{i\frac{\theta}{n}}$ before switching back to Cartesian form?

Comment: After seeing your edit: why? This seems to be the most straightforward way to solve the problem., is there a specific reason to rule it out?

Comment: Again, to react to the edit: the answer will be of the right form $a+ib$; the *method* to get this answer will take a detour *via* transcendental functions, but the final answer will not... unless I'm misunderstanding something about the restriction you impose?

Comment: What Clement said. See the first part of [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1762379/269624)

Comment: It also addresses the "not always possible" thing — if the angle works out to one where sin and cos give nice radicals, then there you are. And if it doesn't, then there you are as well :)

Answer (score 1):

If $p$ and $q$ are integers, you can factor $p+iq$ over the Gaussian integers.  If $p+iq$ has an $n$'th root that is a Gaussian integer, you can derive it from that.  Moreover, a necessary condition is that $p^2+q^2 = (p+iq)(p-iq)$ is the $n$'th power of an integer.