# Closed form for $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n!}{\pi^n x^n} \prod_{k=1}^n \sin \frac{\pi x}{k}$

Tags: definite-integrals, closed-form, infinite-product, zeta-functions

> Is it possible to find some kind of closed form for the following function ?
>
> $$L(x) = \prod_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin \pi \frac{x}{k}}{\pi \frac{x}{k}} = \prod_{k=1}^\infty \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-\frac{x^2}{k^2 n^2})\\ = \exp(-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2m}}{m k^{2m} n^{2m}})=\exp(-\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2m}}{m}\zeta(2m)^2)$$

It converges for $0<x<1$ and this is the interval I'm interested in.

We have the following identities:

$$\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{\zeta(2m)}{m} x^{2m} =\log \frac{\pi x}{\sin \pi x}$$

$$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{\zeta(2m)}{2m+1} x^{2m}= \frac{1}{2} \left(1-\log 2-\log (\sin \pi x)-\frac{1}{2 \pi x}\operatorname {Cl} _{2}(2\pi x) \right)$$

$$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{\zeta(2m)}{m(2m+1)} x^{2m}= \log (2 \pi x)-1+\frac{1}{2 \pi x}\operatorname {Cl} _{2}(2\pi x)$$

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function.

However, I don't know a closed form when zeta is squared.

Using one of the integrals for the zeta function, I have also derived:

$$\frac{1}{L(x)}= \exp \left[ \frac{1}{2} \log \frac{\pi x}{\sin \pi x}+x \int_0^x \log \frac{\pi u}{\sin \pi u} \frac{du}{u^2}+ \\ + 2 \int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan t dt}{e^{2 \pi t}-1}+ \frac{1}{i} \int_0^\infty \frac{dt}{e^{2 \pi t}-1} \left( \log \sin \frac{\pi x}{1+ i t}- \log \sin \frac{\pi x}{1- i t} \right) \right]$$

Or, using automaticallyGenerated's comment, we can simplify:

> $$L(x)= \frac{\sqrt{2 \pi}}{e} \sqrt{\frac{\sin \pi x}{\pi x}} e^{-I_1(x)-I_2(x)}$$

Where:

> $$I_1(x)=x \int_0^x \log \frac{\pi u}{\sin \pi u} \frac{du}{u^2}$$
>
> $$I_2(x)=\frac{1}{i} \int_0^\infty \frac{dt}{e^{2 \pi t}-1} \left( \log \sin \frac{\pi x}{1+ i t}- \log \sin \frac{\pi x}{1- i t} \right) $$

We can derive the following identity:

$$\log \sin (a+i b)= \frac{1}{2} \log ( \cosh^2 b- \cos^2 a)+ i \arctan \frac{\tanh b}{\tan a}$$

Which leads to:

> $$I_2(x)=2 \int_0^\infty \frac{dt}{e^{2 \pi t}-1} \arctan \frac{\tanh \frac{\pi x t}{1+ t^2}  }{\tan \frac{\pi x}{1+ t^2}}   $$

Or:

$$I_2(x)=2 \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{du}{(e^{2 \pi \tan u}-1) \cos^2 u} \arctan \frac{\tanh \frac{\pi x}{2} \sin 2 u  }{\tan \frac{\pi x}{2} (1+ \cos 2u)}   $$

$I_2$ seems hopeless, but I'd love a partial answer for $I_1$ at least.

---

This can be considered a generalization of my [old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1652107/269624), though I just remembered it.

Comment: if you multiply the numerator and denominator of sin arguments by $1 \pm it$ then you might be able to make progress via log A - log B = log A/B and some sin addition and/or subtraction identities?

Comment: $$2\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan t dt}{e^{2 \pi t}-1} = 1-\frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi)$$ according to [Binet's second log gamma formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsLogGammaFormulas.html)

Comment: @automaticallyGenerated, thank you, I edited

Comment: @reuns, using Euler product for $\text{sinc} \pi x$, expanding the logarithms in Taylor series, then changing the order of summation

Comment: The [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Definition) of this function, as the limit of $$f_1(x)=\begin{cases}1,&|x|<1/2\\ \color{gray}{1/2,}&\color{gray}{|x|=1/2}\\0,&|x|>1/2\end{cases},\qquad f_n(x)=\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}f_{n-1}(x+y/n)\,dy$$ is also worth looking at (nice pictures, weird computations...).